# Help with cross join creating a week view calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calendar

Hi all i have a table called bookings like this ( Ive bolded the columns to align)

```
CustID  VenueID BookingDt                   Session

45      44      2010-03-20 00:00:00.000     PM      
45      44      2010-03-27 00:00:00.000     PM      
45      44      2009-10-18 00:00:00.000     PM          
45      44      2009-10-24 00:00:00.000     PM
```

I have another table called Venues

```
oID oLocation   oPitch

1   Left Park   Rugby
2   Right Park  Rugby
```

The tables are inter joined by Venues.oID=bookings .CustID

i want to make a table such as this

X Column = week days
Y column = locations

```
oID  oSun oMon oTue oWed oThu oFri oSat

1    x          x    x         x
2    x    x          x    x    x   x x
```

I believe i have to do a cross join with the data from the bookings Database

Eg

```
select distinct v.olocation , b.BookingDt from oVenue V 
cross join tblBookings B
Where B.VenueID=V.oID
and  DATEPART( wk, b.BookingDt )='44' 
and  DATEPART( yy, b.BookingDt )='2009'
```

But this does  oID and Date, i want it to do check to see if that date is there, if so place a x in its place other wise place a '' in its place.

Not sure the best way to proceed.
Any help is muchly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you already restricted the week and year in your query, this is how to display it:

```
select
  v.olocation,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 1 then 'x' else '' end) Sun,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 2 then 'x' else '' end) Mon,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 3 then 'x' else '' end) Tue,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 4 then 'x' else '' end) Wed,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 5 then 'x' else '' end) Thu,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 6 then 'x' else '' end) Fri,
  max(case DATEPART(weekday, b.BookingDt) When 7 then 'x' else '' end) Sat
from
(
    select distinct v.olocation , b.BookingDt 
    from oVenue V 
    LEFT JOIN tblBookings B on B.VenueID=V.oID
    and  DATEPART( wk, b.BookingDt )='44' 
    and  DATEPART( yy, b.BookingDt )='2009' 
) selweek
group by v.olocation
```

Comment: I'm still not clear why you'd need a CROSS JOIN for this.  You'd need a LEFT JOIN in order to assign bookings to the appropriate venue IDs.

Comment: Me neither, I'm only getting OP's result and working on that. Reuse, baby!

Comment: :)  I think your suggestion would do what he wants if you make the CROSS JOIN a LEFT JOIN on the IDs specified.

Comment: Just did it, hope it helps OP

Comment: Oh, it could be INNER JOIN just as well. With LEFT JOIN, b.BookingDt would be NULL in case of no match, consequently it would affect neither of the CASEs. Same would be with INNER JOIN, only INNER JOIN would yield less rows = potentially faster. Unless I'm missing something, of course. +1 anyway, the idea is working regardless.

Comment: I definitely missed one thing: with INNER JOIN some `oLocation`'s could be filtered out completely. So, no, LEFT JOIN is certainly better if all `oLocation`'s should be represented in the output.

Answer (score 1):

How the data is displayed should be a front-end issue, not a database issue. I wouldn't concentrate on things like putting "x" in a specific spot. Return the data that your application needs to fill in your calendar and have the front-end do that.

That said, in order to create results like what you're looking for, you're missing a set of data - the set of calendar days. You can do this with a temporary table, a CTE, or a permanent table in your database, but you basically need a table that gives you all of the days in question as a resultset. You can then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from that table to your bookings table and use `CASE` to fill in values based on whether or not a matched bookings row was found.